# Python and Selenium - PHPSESSID cookie is logging me in

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, phantomjs, python-requests, session-cookies

I am trying to scrape data off of a website to create a list of the ten most recent rolls. My code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.csgodouble.com/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#List of past rolls
rolls = tree.xpath('//div[@class="past"]/text()')

print 'Rolls: ', rolls
```

Why is no data outputted? The python shell only prints

> Rolls:  [ ]

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Problem with the PHPSESSID. I was also able to get PhantomJS working, but running Firefox so I can see the webpage. Thank you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.add_cookie({'name': 'PHPSESSID', 'value': '<MY PHPSESSID>'})
print(driver.get_cookie('PHPSESSID'))
driver.get("http://www.csgodouble.com/index.php")

#rolls = (driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="past"]').text)
#print 'Rolls: ', rolls
```

The PHPSESSID is not logging me in. When I run the code, it only brings me to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rolls on that website are dynamically generated, so you won't be able to access them directly through the page content. Instead, you'll have to use Selenium WebDriver together with PhantomJS to "run" the webpage in a headless browser. Then you'll be able to access the rolls information in a similar way.

One problem you'll face is having to login into CSGoDouble with WebDriver. You'll have to replicate your session data after logging into the website with your normal web browser in your source code.

To get this data, install [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) in Chrome, go to http://www.csgodouble.com/, click on the cookie button, and you'll see the relevant cookie called PHPSESSID.  If you add the cookie like this:

```
driver.add_cookie({'name': 'PHPSESSID', 'value': 'the value of that cookie'})
print(driver.get_cookie('PHPSESSID'))
```

(See http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.add_cookie)

Then do something like this:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="past"]').text)
```

You should be able to get the rolls information. I'm not totally sure if this will work, but try it and comment if you have any questions.

**Update:**

The following code works for me using ChromeDriver:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome() # or webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get("http://www.csgodouble.com/index.php")
driver.add_cookie({'name': 'PHPSESSID', 'value': 'abcd2efg3hijk62lmn1op'})
print(driver.get_cookie('PHPSESSID'))
driver.get("http://www.csgodouble.com/index.php")

time.sleep(3)

rolls = driver.find_element_by_id('past').text
print('Rolls: ', rolls)
```

You can replace `webdriver.Chrome()` with `webdriver.Firefox()`.

1. It's necessary to add the cookie once webdriver gets to that URL in order to attach it.
2. Once the cookie is added, refresh the page so that it gets that you are logged in.
3. `time.sleep(3)` is a crude way of waiting for the page to load before scraping information. You can investigate more elegant methods if you'd like.
4. Rolls are stored in a `div` with id `past`.

Comment: I followed what you said. However, when i try to run PhantomJS instead of Firefox as the webdriver, it gives me an error. "'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH." Is PhantomJS required or can I use firefox instead? Also, added driver.add_cookie({'PHPSESSID': '<mysessid>'}), but it does not automatically log me in. Thank you.

Comment: Did "pip install selenium==2.7", now I only have one error when trying to run PhantomJSL "Python Selenium 'WebDriver' object has no attribute error"

Comment: @Raxzon Sorry about the late response. PhantomJS isn't necessary (and it needs extra installation), and FirefoxDriver and ChromeDriver would just make a browser window. Could you update your question with your webdriver code and a screenshot of that window?

Comment: @Raxzon Shoot, I got the add_cookie syntax completely wrong. I've edited my answer with the correct code. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: @Raxzon Be proactive. Read up on Selenium documentation (hint: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html) Inspect  csgodouble.com with your web browser and find out what the page layout really is. When you make a significant effort to troubleshoot by yourself, then you will truly learn. Good luck!